# Microcontroller software intrerrupts how do they work

Tags: microcontroller

I was reading about micro-controller interrupts, and I have a question does the save of the current state happen for software interrupts too or just for hardware interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The general concept behind any interrupt is that it can suspend the execution of the underlying program without that program realising it has been interrupted. This requires storing of the CPU and (some) register states and their restoration once the interrupt service routine has completed. The CPU typically has special hardware mechanism for doing this.

Software interrupts share the same mechanism and so the state is saved and restored.

Note, however, that the normal use for software interrupts is on more complex microprocessors where they allow a safe hardware mechanism for moving between privilege modes - e.g. your application and an operating system. On a low level microcontroller they are of little use, as if you already know you want to call the piece of code in the interrupt, you might as well just call it directly as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the state saved is minimal: just enough to restore the previous state when the only action of the ISR is `RTI`. Usually just the instruction pointer (and code segment) and flags. The whole processor state is not saved, otherwise it would place too much overhead on a time-critical interrupt. It is up the the ISR to save and restore anything more than the bare-bones mechanism of the processor interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, yes as Jon has described, but software interrupts can be used as your interface to the operating system, and for that use case you likely will be setting up registers as parameters into the software interrupt.  And expect registers when it returns to be the result.

So software interrupts, can be treated like hardware interrupts and you have to preserve the state, or they can be treated as or used as fancy function calls and you have parameters going in and

Answer (score 0):

In short it's a maybe.

Without knowing the exact example I couldn't say. What gets saved or doesn't get saved really depends on which software is generating/receiving the interrupt.

At low levels there is a lot of concern about speed at which things happen. And hence work that may not need to be done is avoided. Therefore there is no point in *"saving your state"* if you don't intend to modify it. So it really depends on what exactly we are talking about.

This is where specifications come into play. Operating systems and processors all specify exactly what **state** they **do save** and what state they **do not save** and depending on your specific problem the answer may differ...

@dwelch's answer explains it for Linux. (which is closest to what you were asking for)

@Jon's answer explains it for processors in general.

@weather-vane's answer explains it for micro-controllers.

These are all specific examples. If you were working with FreeRTOS on a micro-controller you would have to probably make your own software interrupt protocol and define it yourself in which case you can choose to save state or leave the responsibility to the caller. In the end, it is just a choice that a programmer that wrote the system made and hence you must go find his notes *and read them*.

In the end, it is mostly a gentlemen agreement.